# Time difference is an unreadable large number in the Console output

Tags: ios, date, logging

Kind of new on iOS and this NSDate is killing me..
I just want to grab the time difference.. so what I did

```
NSDate *start=[NSDate date];
NSLog(@"Start date %d", start);

//---- some for loop jobs here ----

NSDate *end=[NSDate date];
NSLog(@"End date %d", end);
double timedifference= [end timeIntervalSinceDate:start];
NSLog(@"response time %d", timedifference);
```

And the result I got in the console..

```
2011-08-27 12:27:51.505 TabNav[8153:e903] Start date 172118224
2011-08-27 12:27:53.304 TabNav[8153:e903] End date 92503392
2011-08-27 12:27:53.304 TabNav[8153:e903] response time 1073741824
```

How can I convert response time 1073741824 to second ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is just a matter of formatting:

```
NSDate *start=[NSDate date];
NSLog(@"Start date %@", start);
                    ^

//---- some for loop jobs here ----

NSDate *end=[NSDate date];
NSLog(@"End date %@", end);
                  ^
double timedifference= [end timeIntervalSinceDate:start];
NSLog(@"response time %f", timedifference);
                       ^
```

Comment: @Will - next time you will be aware of that :)